# jQuery UI Selectmenu style is not right

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a select element on my page and I've called the `selectmenu` function on it.  The function executes as expected and the styles are applied.  However, when I click on the (well-styled) drop down button, the menu opens with space between the top of the menu and the drop down button, and each menu item is preceded by a bullet point.  The padding in the menu is all wrong as well.  I have verified that `selectmenu.css` is being loaded into the page.  Any idea what's going on?

**Edit**: The downvotes are real.  Apparently you want to see the code.  Should be a good read.

Select:

```
<select>
    <option>dafuq</option>
    <option>isgoingon</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select").selectmenu();
</script>
```

The problem obviously lies somewhere in my jQuery files, maybe a version problem.  I was hoping someone had seen this before and could answer the question with the little information I have available to provide.  Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean it's a bad question guys.

Comment: Please show us. Add a snippet or jsFiddle link.

Comment: what's `selectmenu.css`? the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) uses `style.css` and `jquery-ui.css`

Comment: It's in the themes/base folder.  I'm using ASP NET MVC and that's how it copied everything out when I installed with the Library Package Manager